# What is the difference between xsl:copy and xsl:copy-of in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't see the difference between `xsl:copy` and `xsl:copy-of`.

Which one should I use in which situation?

Comment: Well look into the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy and http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of.

Comment: Where did you look for explanations of the two instructions, and what was it about the explanations that you found confusing?

Answer (score 28):

**In short**, [**`xsl:copy`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) is a shallow copy; [**`xsl:copy-of`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) is a deep copy.

### When to use `xsl:copy` vs `xsl:copy-of`

- Use [**`xsl:copy`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) when you want to copy ***just the context item*** and
  have other plans for the children of the context item.
- Use [**`xsl:copy-of`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) when you want to copy ***XPath-selected nodes and
  their children, recursively.***

### Notes for xsl:copy

- The [**`xsl:copy`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) instruction copies the context item but none
  of its children nodes.
- This is a shallow copy.
- The [**`xsl:copy`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) instruction ***cannot*** have a `@select` XPath.

A very common use of `xsl:copy` can be found in the [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that here the node itself is copied via [**`xsl:copy`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#shallow-copy) and the children nodes are then transformed via `xsl:apply-templates`, giving other templates a chance to intervene in the transformation.

### Notes for xsl:copy-of

- The [**`xsl:copy-of`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) instruction evaluates the XPath in its ***required*** `@select` attribute and copies the selected nodes and their children nodes, recursively.
- This is a deep copy.
- The [**`xsl:copy-of`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) instruction ***must*** have a `@select` XPath.

Notice that [**`xsl:copy-of`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of) could have been used in the identity transformation, however the flexibility afforded by allowing other templates the chance to match during the recursion would have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

`xsl:copy` is a shallow copy. Use it if all you want is to copy the current node (the "context item" in spec-speak).
`xsl:copy-of` is a deep copy. Use it if you want to copy the complete node tree under the current node. For a more thorough and complete explanation read the spec that has been linked to from the first comment.