# What is the difference between 'xsl:copy-of' and 'xsl:sequence'?

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the difference between 'xsl:copy-of' and 'xsl:sequence'

Comment: It would be easier to answer *"what do  `xsl:copy-of` and `xsl:sequence` have in common?"*. Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In very many situations they are interchangeable. One difference is that xsl:copy-of has more options (validation, copy-namespaces, etc). But most of the time you could use either.

There is a formal difference in that `xsl:copy-of` creates new nodes, while `xsl:sequence` returns a reference to existing nodes. That matters if, for example you use the "is" operator on the result, or if you use generate-id(), or if you navigate outside the subtree (e.g. to the parent of the copied node).

It's fair to say that 90% of the time people use `xsl:copy-of` in preference to `xsl:sequence` because that's what you did in XSLT 1.0, not because they really want a copy made.

Answer (score 4):

`xsl:copy-of select="expression"` evaluates `expression` and creates a deep copy of the sequence the expression evaluated to while `xsl:sequence select="expression"` evaluates `expression` and returns the sequence the expression evaluated to.

Depending on where you use the instruction that means that for instance a function using e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="doc('file.xml')//foo"/>` returns a sequence of `foo` elements from the file while `<xsl:copy-of select="doc('file.xml')//foo"/>` in the function returns a copy of the `foo` elements from the file.

As long as you are outputting to a result tree it doesn't usually matter whether you use one or the other, but if you select input nodes and want to preserve them and also don't want to waste memory it can often be more efficient to use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:copy-of`.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a clear difference with an example.

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vCopy" as="document-node()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vSequence" as="document-node()">
            <xsl:sequence select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="generate-id(.), 
                              generate-id($vCopy),
                              generate-id($vSequence)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs with any input source something similar to:

```
d2047 d2048d2047 d2047
```

**Do note**: `xsl:sequence` retains node identity, `xsl:copy` creates a new node.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:copy-of` copies the selected item as a deep copy.

- See also [What is the difference between xsl:copy and xsl:copy-of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704724/290085)

`xsl:sequence` is used to construct an ordered list of nodes and/or atomic values.

Therefore, use `xsl:copy-of` to make a deep copy of a node that exists in the input document; use `xsl:sequence` to assemble an ordered list from possibly disparate nodes and primitive types.