# Copy-of to copy root and all children to an xml database column

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-mapper

In BizTalk, I'm trying an XSLT with the pattern below.  I have calling a SQL stored procedure, and there are some fields before and after the XML column, but the XML column needs to contain the entire XML from the source document.

I have tried two ways, shown below.  The first one results in the root node being copied to the right place, but none of its children.  I [read earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704724/what-is-the-difference-between-xslcopy-and-xslcopy-of) that copy-of is deep-copy (whereas copy is a shallow copy), so not sure why it's not copying the children recursively.

**Try 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns99="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/DCMS_BLD1" 
xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:USP_INS_DIH_RECORD">

            <ns99:Field1>NealTest2</ns99:Field1>

            <ns99:Field2XmlColumn>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*"/>
            </ns99:Field2XmlColumn>

            <ns99:FieldCreatedDateTime>TODAY</ns99:FieldCreatedDateTime>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Try 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" 
version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns99="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/DCMS_BLD1" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:USP_INS_DIH_RECORD">
            <ns99:Field1>NealTest2</ns99:Field1>
            <ns99:Field2XmlColumn>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            </ns99:Field2XmlColumn>
            <ns99:FieldCreatedDateTime>Today</ns99:FieldCreatedDateTime>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Someone in comment asked for sample input. The input shouldn't matter, since it is a direct copy, but here's a dummy example:

```
<ns0:dummy xmlns:ns0="http://myschema.dummy">
    <ns0:firstname>John</ns0:firstname>
    <ns0:lastname>Doe</ns0:lastname>
</ns0:dummy>
```

I removed the C#, and tried it outside of BizTalk on a site like this: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php# and it worked fine.  But it didn't create a shareable link with my data/xsl.

I have also changed the namespace in the xslt to ns99 so it won't conflict with ns0 in the incoming data.

Comment: Can you please add sample input?  Also actual vs expected output might also be helpful.

Comment: Both tries should work. Probably something else is wrong.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - I added sample input to the question (and stripped out the C#) but the input is irrelevant, as it should all get mapped to the XML column for the database.  I changed namespace to n99 in the XSLT.  Works fine on an XSLT tester website.  I'll play more with it in BizTalk.  I'll check to see if the ns0 is the problem in BizTalk.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I had an input file in my "test map" in BizTalk that did not have any child elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with XSLT.  I was testing with an input file that only had a root element.